# How to set the name or caption of a new process created by multiprocessing in python?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, wmi

as the question said, i tried this:

```
multiprocessing.Process(target=test, name="test")
```

but in my system(Win10), it's name and caption still be "Python.exe".
and i notice that when i use opencv-python to create a window, there will be a new process named be same as the window:

```
cv2.imshow("test_pic", test_pic)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

how dose it work?

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile because i want to see the memory footprint of different processing easily (in Windows Task Manager)